# ReactJS: How to solve mapping multiple object array

Tags: json, reactjs

Hi I'm new in ReactJS Framework.
I have problem regarding how to get the value of sec1 object and sec2 object to the API Response. and how to render return the value to my html page.

I have here my constructor codes and my response data.

```
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
        sec1: [],
        sec2: []
    }
}
componentDidMount() {

        axios.get('/api/community').then(response => {
           this.setState({
               sec1: response.data,
               sec2: response.data
           })
        })

    }
```

**My Console Log**

[image: my 2 object]

Comment: sec1: response.data[0].sec1[0]
sec2: response.data[0].sec2[0]

Comment: Thanks @ChrisAdams

Comment: it's should be `sec1: response.data[0].sec1` and `sec2: response.data[0].sec2`

Comment: @OlivierBoissé let me try

Comment: @OlivierBoissé yah. same output. without [0]

Answer (score 2):

Difficult without a clearer view of the data, but something like this perhaps?

```
sec1: response.data[0].sec1[0]
sec2: response.data[0].sec2[0]
```

Not ideal, but you could try drilling down bit by bit with console.log statements until you get what you need.

To me your data looks like...

> array
>
> > prop
> >
> > > array
> > >
> > > > json object

Comment: why `sec1: response.data[0].sec1[0]` and not `sec1: response.data[0].sec1` ?

Comment: Because, or at least to me, the screenshot looks like sec1 is an array.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the above answers:

Option 1:

```
sec1: response.data[0].sec1[0]
sec2: response.data[0].sec2[0]
```

Will store sec1 and sec2 as objects. Mainly used if you know that sec1 and sec2 can never have more than one object and you need to drill down into each object in your application.

Option2 :

```
sec1: response.data[0].sec1
sec2: response.data[0].sec2
```

will store sec1 and sec2 as arrays. Mainly used when sec1 and sec2 are collection of objects and you need to iterate over each object to display/manipulate the data.

**Choose wisely depending on your use-case.**

Comment: hi shivam the option 2 is working to my html page.. however if i use the option it gives me error.

Comment: If you post some code/details about the error, I can take a look at it.